# Protect the login from malacious input

Tags: flask

Flask login redirects to `/login?next=/protected/123` when I am not logged in. Anybody can as well use `/login?next=phishingsite.com/give_me_your_password_again` since I use:

```
redirect(request.args.get('next','/')
```

How do I verify that the URL is present in the same app?

Comment: As the Flask-Login [example](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#login-example) suggests, you can implement a function called `next_is_valid` to implement all your concerns for the `next` URL.

Comment: @kiran.koduru what logic should I implement inside `next_is_valid`?

Comment: Did the example below help?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a function called `next_is_valid` to check if the `next` originated from the same host like so:

```
from urlparse import urlparse

def next_is_valid(url):
    parsed = urlparse(url)
    if parsed.hostname and parsed.hostname == request.url_root:
        return True

    # if there is no hostname since it's a relative URL
    elif not parsed.hostname:
        return True
    return False


# in your flask app route handler check if next_is_valid returns True
if not next_is_valid(request.args.get('next')):
    abort(400)
```